# Formik FieldArray handling yup validationschema with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation, formik, yup

I have a dynamic form which can be created with formik's fieldarray. I have no issue generating new form fields and validating them. I am using typescript and below code shows up type error on errors field.

```
<Formik
  enableReinitialize
  initialValues={{
    formValues: [
      {
        socialPlatform: "",
        url: "",
      },
    ],
  }}
  onSubmit={(values) => {
    console.log(values);
  }}
  validationSchema={validationSchema}
>
  {({ values, handleChange, errors, touched }) => {
    return (
      <Form>
        <FieldArray name="formValues">
          {({ push }) => (
            <React.Fragment>
              {values.formValues.map((formValue, index) => (
                <Field
                  id={`formValues.${index}.socialPlatform`}
                  name={`formValues.${index}.socialPlatform`}
                  label="Social Platform"
                  placeholder="Select Social Media"
                  options={socialMedias}
                  value={formValue.socialPlatform}
                  onChangeHandler={handleChange}
                  hasError={
                    errors.formValues[index].socialPlatform &&
                    touched.formValues[index].socialPlatform
                  }
                  errorMessage={errors.formValues[index].socialPlatform}
                  component={Dropdown}
                />
              ))}
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
        </FieldArray>
      </Form>
    );
  }}
</Formik>
```

Below part shows Object is possibly 'undefined' and Property 'socialPlatform' does not exist on type 'string | FormikErrors<{ socialPlatform: string; url: string; }>'.
Property 'socialPlatform' does not exist on type 'string'. What should I do?

```
hasError={
  errors.formValues[index].socialPlatform &&
  touched.formValues[index].socialPlatform
}
errorMessage={errors.formValues[index].socialPlatform}
```

Edit: Well since I couldn't find anything meaningful about the issue I had to pass touched and errors props to Input component and handle validation with Formik's getIn function as below;

```
<Field
  id={`formValues.${index}.socialPlatform`}
  name={`formValues.${index}.socialPlatform`}
  label="Social Platform"
  placeholder="Select Social Media"
  options={socialMedias}
  value={formValue.socialPlatform}
  onChangeHandler={handleChange}
  handleError={errors}
  handleTouched={touched}
  component={Input}
/>
```

and then inside Input component;

```
import { getIn } from "formik";

const errorMessage = FormikError(handleError, handleTouched, name);

const FormikError = (errors: any, touched: any, fieldName: any) => {
  const error = getIn(errors, fieldName);
  const touch = getIn(touched, fieldName);
  return touch && error ? error : null;
};
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same issue

Comment: @SethLutske I have edited my question for the workaround I have applied.